# Game developing on the oculus rift

Tags: oculus

My question is, do I need the oculus rift development kit to develop games or can I do it with a standard pair of oculus rift,and if I can do it with a standard pair of oculus rift why does the development kit exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dev Kit existed to get the Oculus product in the hands of developers before the actual consumer product existed.

This was partially to combat the chicken-egg problem (no games mean no consumer interest, no consumers mean no developer interest).

Another reason was to get developers accustomed to the concept of VR as it has different challenges from a user/gameplay perspective.

The third reason is to create hype and press interest as VR is a relative new tech (if you ignore the 90s experiments).

The reason dev kits for consoles or other tech exists is usually because those have features required for development such as extra video connectors to monitor system internals, means to attach debuggers to processes running on the hardware or simoly a opened operating system to be able to deploy software easily.

The Oculus does not 'run' the software but can be regarded as an extra screen and some input controllers- thus you can develop fine with the regular consumer kit.

The tools may require licenses to get access to the SDK (Software Development Kit) that holds libraries and code samples to actually do the development. Though some (I think UE4- not sure)may come with the required libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for informing me about these things :)